# How to add increasing id to the result of reduceByKey and sort with mapValues

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD of (key, value) such as":

```
val rddInit = sc.parallelize(List((1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 5), (2, 7),(2,1), (3, 10)))
val rddData = rddInit..groupByKey.mapValues(row=>{row.toList.sortWith(_>_)})
val rddRestored = rddData.flatMap{
  case (k, v) => v.map((k, _))
}
rddRestored.collect().foreach(println)
```

The result is :

```
(1,3)
(1,2)
(2,7)
(2,5)
(2,1)
(3,10)
```

I want the result like:

```
(1,3,1)
(1,2,2)
(2,7,1)
(2,5,2)
(2,1,3)
(3,10,1)
```

Is there any other way to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is `zipWithIndex` to create the *ranking* of the *values* of the grouped `RDD`. `zipWithIndex` would start from `0` so you need some modification to start from `1`.

The following solution should work for you

```
val rddInit = sc.parallelize(List((1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 5), (2, 7),(2,1), (3, 10)))
val rddData = rddInit.groupByKey.mapValues(row=>{row.toList.sortWith(_>_)}.zipWithIndex.map{ case (r, i) => (r,i+1)})
val rddRestored = rddData.flatMap{
  case (k, v) => {
    v.map(x =>(k, x._1, x._2))
  }
}
rddRestored.collect().foreach(println)
```

You should be having the following output

```
(1,3,1)
(1,2,2)
(3,10,1)
(2,7,1)
(2,5,2)
(2,1,3)
```

Comment: Don' care start with 0 or 1,It seems get  (1,3,1)
(1,2,2)
(3,10,3)
(2,7,4)
(2,5,5)
(2,1,6)   not group by key

Comment: look at my result . it doesn't match with what you have commented. you must be missing some brackets I guess.

Comment: val rddData = rddInit.groupByKey.mapValues(row=>{row.toList.sortWith(_>_)}.mapValues(row=>(row,row._2.zipWithIndex))    I solve the problem like this ,thank you

Comment: thats great. :) happy to have helped you :) You can accept the answer if you want